# Google Custom Search (User quota Limits)

Tags: google-custom-search, limits

We are planning to use Google Custom Search API to achieve one of our requirements. During the PT cycle we run into an issue of exceeding 100requests/100seconds/user limit (Since the API calls are happening on the Server Side,most likely the same limit is going to be exceeded in production as well). Is there a way to go around it(other than proxying API calls)? Ideally would be to white list the IP address so that the limit does not apply to it.

Will greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Roman.